# How to set setInterval time depending on time of day

Tags: javascript

I have to run a group of functions every so often, during the day I have to run them every 2 minutes, in the evening they need to run every 3 minutes and at night they need to run every 5 minutes. Right now I'm running them like this, with every function running every 2 minutes at all times of the day.

```
const function1 = () => DO_SOMETHING

const function2 = () => DO_SOMETHING_ELSE

const function3 = () => DO_SOMETHING_ANTOTHER_THING

setInterval(() => {
    function1()
}, 1000 * 60 * 2)

setInterval(() => {
    function2()
}, 1000 * 60 * 2)

setInterval(() => {
    function3()
}, 1000 * 60 * 2)
```

Does anyone know how I can set this up so that the time variable changes depening on what time of day it is?

Comment: Do you want it to change if someone opens the page and leaves it running all day? Or do you just want to set the interval once when the page opens and leave it at that interval for as long as the page is open?

Comment: It will stay open on a server even when no one is using the site. It will just start once, and then run forever, I just need to know how to set it to run every x minutes, where x changes depending on the time of day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using a `setTimeout` that triggers itself, instead of a `setInterval`.

Overview:

- Set up a function that builds your timeout with the correct duration for the current time using `Date().getHours()` to find the time.
- Call this builder function on load.
- Set up a result function, and call the builder function inside there as well.
- Add whatever the desired result is to the result function.

Example:

(You can change the definition of "evening" and "night" using the two if statements)

```js
// This is required if you ever want to use clearTimeout()
let timeoutRefernce = null

// Run the desired code after X amount of time
const result = () => {
  // Start a new iteration of the timer
  newTimeout()
  // Run your resulting code
  // e.g. Call function1, function2 and function3
  console.log('Result')
}

const newTimeout = () => {
  const time = new Date().getHours()
  let minutes = 2
  // Is it evening? (Between 5pm and 10pm)
  if (time > 17 && time < 22) {
    minutes = 3
  }
  // Is it night? (Between 10pm and 6am)
  if (time > 22 || time < 6) {
    minutes = 5
  }
  // Create a new timeout with the relevant duration
  timeoutRefernce = setTimeout(result, 1000 * 60 * minutes)
  console.log(`Hour: ${time}, New timeout created with duration ${minutes} minutes`)
}

// Run the first timeout on load
newTimeout()
```